# Hide one div, unhide another div, scroll to the new unhidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function `closeGeneralHelp` which takes one parameter: `idtag`. The function is supposed to do the following:

a) `slideUp` the "Help" div, 
b) `slideDown` a set of divs and then
c) scroll, jump, or otherwise go to a specific (but dynamically determined) other div of the set of divs that were exposed via the `slideDown`.

I have two classes of divs ("DivsToShow" and "DivToHide"). "DivsToShow" has a few other divs contained in it and each of those divs has a unique `id` (this is what `idtag` is).

Parts (a) and (b) work just fine. Scrolling to the specific (but dynamically determined) div seems to fail no matter what I try. Here is the code. Each /* */ comment block represents a separate, but failed (and flailing) attempt at making this work.

Any help on getting (c) to work? I am a JavaScript / jQuery infant. So any reasonably related advice / pointers are also appreciated.

```
function closeGeneralHelp(idtag){
    $(".DivsToShow").slideDown("slow");
    $(".DivToHide").slideUp("slow");
    /* var divid = document.getElementById(idtag);
    divid.style.display = 'block';
    divid.scrollIntoView(true);  */
    /*  document.getElementById(idtag).scrollIntoView();*/
    /*  $(window).scrollTo(idtag,800,{queue:true});*/
    /* window.location.hash = idtag;*/
    /* window.setTimeout(function() {window.scroll(0, findPos(idtag));}, 5);*/
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you are doing the slideUp/slideDown as "slow", you will probably need to wait until they are complete before you scroll to the "DivsToShow".  Just add the scroll code to the [completion callback of slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

Comment: @Richard Thanks! I did this and it worked just perfectly: $(".DivsToShow").slideDown("slow",function(){document.getElementById(idtag).scrollIntoView();});, what's the SO etiquette for marking this complete?

Comment: Complete? You mean the topic? You mark a answer as solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback function, in this case after the slidedown is done:

```
$(".DivToHide").slideUp("slow");
$(".DivsToShow").slideDown("slow", function(){
    var $ShownDiv = $(this);
    // this is the callback of slidedown, after it is done, perform this:
    $('html,body').scrollTop( $ShownDiv.scrollTop() );

    // Or animated:
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $ShownDiv.scrollTop()}, 1000); // in ms

    // Or more native JS
    document.getElementById( $(ShownDiv)[0].id ).scro‌​‌​llIntoView();
});
```

---

If you have an old jQuery and cant upgrade, you might want to discard `$("#someElement").scrollTop()` in favor of `$('#someElement').offset().top`

Comment: Thanks! These unfortunately did not work. This, however, did: $(".DivsToShow").slideDown("slow",function(){document.getElementById(idtag).scro‌​llIntoView();});

Comment: Ok, I changed `html,body` to `window` which I believe is the correct one. But of your method works, great

Comment: Your answer is nearly correct, if you are referencing window it should be `$(window)` - notice no quotes, but using animate, you were right it should be `$('html,body')`

Comment: Thanks Danny, changed it back. I thought it was that, but I found another solution somewhere which said `'window'` and I had no time to test it, asumed that was correct :)